# Can the compiler infer the return type of a class constructor?

Tags: typescript

Given a class definition:

```
class Foo {

}
```

and a type-parameterised function accepting a class function:

```
function bar<TInstance, TClass extends { new (): TInstance }>(t: TClass): TInstance {
    return new t() // more complicated in reality, focus on the compiler!
}
```

I can call the function on the class constructor without type complaints:

```
const x = bar(Foo)
```

However, the type of `x` here is `{}`, not `Foo`.

I can call it with explicit type parameters:

```
const x = bar<Foo, typeof Foo>(Foo)
```

... but that's really boilerplate-y

**Is there any way to get type inference on this method** to avoid the boilerplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You over complicated your function signature, this version works:

```
function bar<TInstance>(t: { new (): TInstance }): TInstance {
    return new t();
}

const x = bar(Foo); // x is of type Foo
```

Comment: Perfect, I should've thought of that. Thanks!